# PostgreSQL commands not working in virtualenv

Tags: django, windows, postgresql, python-venv

I want to use PostgreSQL as my database in my Django project(my os is windows). I can't run PostgreSQL's commands in the command prompt while venv is activated and out of venv I have access to those commands because I've added PostgreSQL bin directory path to the PATH environmental variable. How can I do this with virtualenv so I can run those commands inside virtualenv?

Thank you.

Comment: can you add stack trace of the error you are getting?

Comment: @Marcelo 'createuser' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

you can open a second cmd
and use it for Postgre